# how to convert a RGB image to its YIQ components in python , and then apply dct transform to compress it?

Tags: python, matplotlib, dct

In matlab we have rgb2ntsc() function to get YIQ components of a RGB image. Is there a similar function available in python (numpy ,matplotlib or scipy libraries)?

Also to apply discrete cosine transform (compress it) we can use dct2() , in matlab , is there a similar function in python?

Comment: It seems like 2 functions in `skimage` and `matlab` are doing the same things but they have different names. I think `rgb2yiq` is a better name.

Answer (score 1):

Are you willing to use a library outside of numpy, scipy, and matplotlib?
If so you can use `skimage.color.rgb2yiq()` from the scikit-image library.